# Inspector does not work with breakpoint

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed that after chrome updates last few days (60.0.3112.113) Chrome Inspector stop working with breakpoints.

What I need to do is highlight all jQuery elements on the page using jquery selector $(".myclass"). This is impossible if I am in break mode (breakpoint). In older versions of Chrome I could do that.

This is very important tool, because I need to check html nodes almost always in breakmode.

How can I restore this setting? My entire work depends of this tool :( Firefox tools are not so intuitive for me.

Comment: Make sure it's not some option you've changed: go to devtools settings and click "restore defaults" button.

Comment: This is not option mess, my co-workers has the same problem

Comment: What does DevTools output when you run `$(".myclass")` in the Console now?

Comment: Do you have a URL or can you create a [Stack Overflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that reproduces this issue?